# android application connect to mysql database

Tags: android

i am using eclipse and i want to connect my android application to my sql database.

my activity.java code is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView resultView;
    private InputStream is;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resultView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
    }

    public void getData() {
       String result = "";
        //the year data to send
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","suman"));

        //http post
        try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/hello/try.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

                Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //convert response to string
        try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Input Reading pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                is.close();

                result=sb.toString();
        } catch(Exception e) {
               Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //parse json data
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                   JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                            ", Name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                            ", Address: "+json_data.getInt("address")+
                            ", Contact: "+json_data.getInt("contact")
                    );
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        } catch(JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

but after run the application database is not show on avd or it show the application stopped unexpectectedly. please try again.

Comment: Please show the exception that causes the app to crash. You can find it in the logs.

Comment: 10-28 18:26:06.026: D/SntpClient(72): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
10-28 18:31:06.091: D/SntpClient(72): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: still this is a problem plz help me:- error show in logcat is java.lang.NullPointerException       'runnig android lint' has encountered a problem - failed

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

Use should use path for localserver

```
http://10.0.2.2 / [your application folder on server] / [php file(.php)];

http://10.0.2.2 /hello/try.php
```

instead of

```
http://127.0.0.1/hello/try.php
```

Please see example

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: thanx nitin, i already apply this but same result

Comment: @sumankumar try to use this androidhive u will get result, i have already used this code for my application.

Comment: still this is a problem plz help me:- error show in logcat is java.lang.NullPointerException 'runnig android lint' has encountered a problem - failed

Comment: @sumankumar please send a php files and database, i will check it

Comment: Add this code in mainactivity.java

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: please refere

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146607/getting-message-from-json/22148248#22148248