# Getting message from JSon

Tags: android

I wrote the code below to get a simple message from a file php that send me a json object, I have no errors in my code and the PHP code work well, can you please help me to find what is the matter with my code :)

JAVA Code :

```
package com.example.httpclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView myListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try{
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //This is our textView element
            myListView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            //Lets try to connect
            try{
                //Create a new client object
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                //Now post to your demo URL
                HttpPost httppost = new     HttpPost("http://goldengym.ma/test/test1.php");

                //Execute the post and get the response
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                //Get the message from the response
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                //Get the content of the message
                InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

                //Convert response to string
                try{
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

                    //Read one line of the response
                    myListView.setText(reader.readLine());

                    //Slow our inputStream
                    webs.close();

                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " +     e.toString());
                }               
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " +     e.toString());
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error " + e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

And there is the PHP Code :

```
<?php

    $result = 'TEST WORKED, WE GOT CONNECTION';

    print json_encode($result);

?>
```

And there is my logcat :

```
03-03 12:35:02.918: I/ActivityManager(1995): Force stopping package com.example.httpclient uid=10118

03-03 12:35:04.518: W/PackageManager(1995): Code path for pkg : com.example.httpclient changing from /data/app/com.example.httpclient-2.apk to /data/app/com.example.httpclient-1.apk

03-03 12:35:04.518: I/ActivityManager(1995): Force stopping package com.example.httpclient uid=10118

03-03 12:35:04.518: W/PackageManager(1995): Resource path for pkg : com.example.httpclient changing from /data/app/com.example.httpclient-2.apk to /data/app/com.example.httpclient-1.apk

03-03 12:35:05.218: I/ActivityManager(1995): Force stopping package com.example.httpclient uid=10118

03-03 12:35:05.493: D/Launcher.LauncherModel(5871):   --> package:com.example.httpclient

03-03 12:35:05.723: D/Launcher.LauncherModel(5871):   --> update package com.example.httpclient

03-03 12:35:05.723: D/Launcher.LauncherModel(5871):   --> package:com.example.httpclient

03-03 12:35:05.913: V/BackupManagerService(1995): updatePackageParticipantsLocked: com.example.httpclient

03-03 12:35:06.188: D/PackageBroadcastService(2465): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.example.httpclient

03-03 12:35:06.523: V/BackupManagerService(1995): updatePackageParticipantsLocked: com.example.httpclient

03-03 12:35:07.598: W/DeepLinking(3458): no deep link install data found for com.example.httpclient

03-03 12:35:07.663: D/PackageBroadcastService(2465): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.example.httpclient

03-03 12:35:07.703: D/PackageAddedReceiver(2234): package added com.example.httpclient

03-03 12:35:08.048: D/PackageBroadcastService(2465): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED and uri=com.example.httpclient
```

Comment: so you have nothing in logcat but your textview is empty afre request?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, exactly I don't have any errors in my log, the textView just don't show anything (empty)

Comment: can you post your logtcat

Comment: of curse I will add it on my post :)

Comment: You are doing network related operation in UI thread. Use Asynctask for it. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21994180/1554935)

Comment: @EL OUFIR Hatim Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Hi sorry I was in university, no not yet :(

Comment: Yeah it worked :D look at the answer with the validate mark :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.example.httpclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView myListView;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //This is our textView element
    myListView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


    //Lets try to connect
    try{
        //Create a new client object
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        //Now post to your demo URL
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/testAndroid/test1.php");

        //Execute the post and get the response
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        //Get the message from the response
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        //Get the content of the message
        InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

        //Convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            //Read one line of the response
            myListView.setText(reader.readLine());

            //Slow our inputStream
            webs.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " +     e.toString());
        }               
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " +     e.toString());
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

PLz try this code, It is working fine. There should use

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

and Manifeast

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.httpclient"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.provider.testdemo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

Comment: okey :D thanks I'll try it right now and I'll tell you the result :D thank you

Comment: Can you help me please on this it's similar : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158091/getting-information-from-mysql-to-android-with-json)

Answer (score 0):

1. Network calls made on the main Thread are disallowed (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)
2. Also, you need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
3. Never use `Exception` to handle your exceptions.
4. Also, I would try to avoid putting a `try-catch` into an other `try-catch`.

Comment: You cannot do a networking operation on the main thread. You need to create your own Thread or use an `AsyncTask` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). 

To be able to do networking operation, you also need to add that tag in your AndroidManifest file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, for the second point I did it already (I add the line of android.permission.INTERNET in my AndroidManifest), but I don't understand the first point (main Thread ? :p ) can you explain more :) thank you

Comment: Most of the code you type in your project are made on the main thread (the one that refresh all the views). Your networking operations need to be made on a Thread you manage yourself. Read that page for info:  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not do the internet operations on main thread. It will give you mainThreadException.
You have to use Asynctask for doing these operations. Then only your able to fetch data from the web services.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

You can use this link to understand how it works.

Comment: I don't know how to use this asynctask :p I'm a really a beginner :D you have a tuto or something that can explain how to do it :D

Answer (score 0):

do it as follows:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private TextView myListView;

    public MyAsyncTask(TextView myListView){
       this.myListView = myListView;
    }
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         String response = null;
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //Now post to your demo URL
            HttpPost httppost = new     HttpPost(params[0]);

            //Execute the post and get the response
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            //Get the message from the response
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            //Get the content of the message
            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

            //Convert response to string
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                response = reader.readLine();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " +     e.toString());
            }finally{
                webs.close();
            }
       return response;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result != null){
            myListView.setText(result);
    }
}
```

In [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) of your activity:

```
new MyAsyncTask(myListView).execute("http://goldengym.ma/test/test1.php");
```

The key method of AsyncTask is doInBackground(), which performs the lengthy operations on a separate thread, while onPostExecute works on the main thread. Refer [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more detail. Also, before making any call to server, you should always check first, whether internet is available. I had not posted that part here. Hope this helps.